# Google Map cluster with images around

Tags: maps, markerclusterer

I am working on project and i need to create google map clusters with images around like it is on image:[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEUvh.png)

Did anyone have a similar problem? Any help?

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: I am trying to show clusters like on image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEUvh.png
e.g if I have cluster with 8 pings, when click on it to show pins like images around

Comment: did you manage to get google maps api... i had put markers with custom longitude/latitude but not the circular clusters...